# coin toss in python, flips coin 1000 times, need to run it 3 times and find average

Tags: python, coin-flipping

Here is what I have so far. The problem asks us to run `coinToss(1000)` a certain number of times. Then find the average number of heads based on the three times it ran. (e.g., If we got 400 heads, 350 heads, and then 600 heads, the program would return 450 heads as the average of the three.) I am stumped here, as I can't figure out how to get this thing to run three times, and return the average. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import random

def coinToss(number):

    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for i in range(0, number):
        flip = int(random.random()*2)
        if (flip == 0):
            heads = heads + 1
        else:
            tails = tails + 1
    return (heads, tails)

def simulatecoinToss(counter):

    for i in range(0, counter):
        coinToss(1000)
        counter = counter -1
    return
```

Comment: you need to save the heads and tail count of each 1000 tosses ...

Comment: i'm not sure where to go from what i have posted. I can't figure out how to save the heads and tail count. or if the code i have for simulatecoinToss makes any sense for what i need to do, with what i have, does it actually run the coinToss(1000) 3 times?

Comment: No, you need to run `simulatecoinToss(3)` to run `coinToss(1000)` 3 times. But why is there `counter = counter -1` in the definition of `simulatecoinToss`? Is it your code?

Comment: Im guessing not... its homework that he copied from someone ...

Comment: i figured i needed a counter to now how many times to run coinToss(1000)? i started off without the counter, but i couldn't get it to run so i threw it in to see if it would help.(Joran, thanks but i didn't copy it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
simulateCoinToss(counter,number):
    trial_heads = (coinToss(number)[0] for _ in xrange(counter))
    average_heads = float(sum(trial_heads))/counter
    return (average_heads, number-average_heads)
```

*Note: you don't actually need to record anything about tails (as heads+tails=number).*